# OFDM interpretation data

Tags: ofdm

I'm studying OFDM modulation. I understand that a bit stream comes in and you get the modulated signals (for example QPSK). Let's say we have 4 subcarriers. At the entrance to the P/S I have [1+j,1-1j,-1-j,1+j]. this data that enters serial will exit parallel towards the IFFT. What result do I get at the end of the IFFT?

Mathematically speaking

Comment: you get the IFFT of these four values. That's mathematically speaking just a fast implementation of the IDFT. So, what's really the question here? "It's the IFFT of the values" is the full mathematical answer.

Comment: Scusa ho posto male la domanda. In ingresso all'ifft ho (X0,X1,X2,X3). Il segnale modulato QPSK racchiuso in Xn non viene mappato su una singola carrirer ma viene "divisa" su 4 carrier differente legate all'ifft giusto?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand Italian! But I think your first sentence is "Sorry, I posted the wrong question". In that case, please *edit* your question to actually ask what you mean to ask (and please do it in English!).